# A combination of methods in a list

Tags: java

In a `Gate` class I have method `public List<Signal> inspect(List<Signal> inputs)` which should contain a combination of `feed()`, `propagate()`, and `read()`. That's the only method I have left to finish but getting an error. Could smb please help me with this method? NOTE: `propagate()` is left abstract to be overriden by childclasses of `Gate` class. The method `public List<Signal> inspect(List<Signal> inputs)` should combine `feed()`, `propagate()`, and `read()`.

import java.util.*;

```
public abstract class Gate implements Logic {

    private List<Wire> inputs;
    private Wire output;
    private String name;

    public Gate(String name, List<Wire> ins, Wire out)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.output = out;

        if(ins.size() == 0 || ins.isEmpty())
            throw new ExceptionLogicParameters(false, 1, 0);
        else 
            this.inputs = ins;
    }

    @Override
    public void feed(List<Signal> inSigs)
    {
        if(inSigs.size() != inputs.size())
            throw new ExceptionLogicParameters(false, inputs.size(), inSigs.size());
        else
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < inSigs.size(); i++)
            {
                inputs.get(i).setSignal(inSigs.get(i));
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void feed(String name)
    {
        if(!(this.name.equals(name)))
                throw new ExceptionLogicMalformedSignal(name.charAt(0), "Invalid logic input");
        else
        {
            Signal signalValue = Signal.fromString(name.charAt(0));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public List<Signal> read()
    {
        List<Signal> signals = new ArrayList<>();
        signals.add(output.getSignal());

        return signals;
    }

    @Override
    public abstract boolean propagate();

    @Override
    public List<Signal> inspect(List<Signal> inputs)
    {
        List<Signal> allMethods = new ArrayList<>();
        allMethods.add(this.feed(inputs));
        allMethods.add(this.propagate());
        allMethods.add(this.read());

    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return this.name+"( " + inputs.toString() + " | " + output.toString() + " )";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other)
    {
        if(other instanceof Gate)
        {
            Gate someGate = (Gate)other;
            return (this.inputs == someGate.inputs) && (this.output.equals(someGate.output)
                    && (this.name.equals(someGate.name)));
        }
        else 
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats a bit much code to sort through when trying to understand the question. Could you trim it down to just enough code to express the question, and then put some text at the bottom of the question explaining what you have tried?

Comment: Sure! @ArthurUlfeldt. I would just remove the code of the Signal class as well as the setters and getters as I think it's not that important for now.

Answer (score 1):

All your methods have no return type.

When you do this

```
    allMethods.add(this.feed(inputs));
    allMethods.add(this.propagate());
    allMethods.add(this.read());
```

It would not return anything and hence nothing is added to the list which will throw error.

Your `list` of of type `signal`

```
List<Signal> allMethods = new ArrayList<>();
```

You need to change the return type of all methods to `Signal` to add them to the list. Like you cant add an `Integer` to a `List<String>` you cannot add anything else than type `Signal` to the `List<Signal>`

I'm no sure of your code logic and if you can change the return type or not, but changing all methods return type to `Signal` should work fine.

Also, you need a return statement for

```
public List<Signal> inspect(List<Signal> inputs)
```

You have to always `return` something if method is not void and the return type should be same as function type